# What is the meaning of ハードルガンガン?

Tags: grammar, translation, manga, kansai-ben

I can't figure out the meaning of the following sentence found in a manga

> これアカン**やつやぞ**何か言わんと**ハードルガンガン**上がってく**やつやぞ**ー！

I'm having not only one, but several doubts in this sentence.

Starting by ハードルガンガン, wich  seems to form an idiom along with 上がって

The use of やつやぞ, if it is a fixed expression or only やつ + **や** + ぞ

To put a little background, the speaker is thinking of ways to impress someone else and worried he is not gonna fulfill their expectations

Parsing it would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 「これアカンやつやぞ何か言わんとハードルガンガン上がってくやつやぞー！」

To insert punctuations and the omitted particles if that helped you a little, it would look like:

> 「これ**は**アカンやつやぞ！何か言わんとハードル**が**ガンガン上がってくやつやぞー！」

To translate this Kansai speech into Standard Japanese, it would be:

> 「これは**いけない**やつ**だ**ぞ！何か**言わない**とハードルがガンガン上がっていくやつ**だ**ぞー！」

「あかん」 means "no good" in Kansai.

The 「と」 in 「何かいわんと」 is a conditional marker -- "***if***".

「やつ」 here means "thing", "one", "situation", etc. and **not** "dude".  It should refer to the action of trying to impress someone.

「やぞ」 in Kansai is an equivalent of 「だぞ」 in Standard.  It is a sentence-ender for declaration/affirmation.

「ハードルが上がる」 is a set phrase meaning "the bar is raised", "the bar rises higher", etc.  For some reason, this phrase has been extremely popular the last couple of decades.

「ガンガン」 is an onomatopoeia meaning "extensively", "again and again", etc.  In this context, "higher and higher" would fit the best.

「何か言わんとハードルガンガン上がってく」 is a relative clause that modifies the noun 「やつ」.

My own TL:

> "This (one/situation) is no good!  This is the kind of situation where the bar will get raised higher and higher if you keep silent!"

Comment: Thank you very much! I still struggle with dialects and colloquialism.